# (proposed) elegant solution to IMO 2003 P1

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

The problem:

$S$ is the set ${1,2,...,10^6}$. Show that for any $101$ element subset $A$ of $S$ we can find $100$ distinct elements $x_i$ of $S$ such that the sets:

{$a + x_i$$|$$a \in{A}$} are pairwise disjoint

Solution:

Form the set ${a_1, ..., a_{101}}$. Say we have four $i, j, k, m$ such that:

$a_i + x_k = a_j + x_m$

$a_i - a_j = x_m - x_k$

There are atmost ${101 \choose 2}$ possible LHS and ${100 \choose 2}$ possible RHS. There are atleast $10^6 - 1$ possible differences of the set $S$ ($k - 1$ for $1 < k ≤ 10^6$)

If we can assign a set of differences to RHS none of which are in the set of differences of LHS, then the proposition is true. We can do this if:

${101 \choose 2}$ $+$ ${100 \choose 2}$  $≤$ $10^6 - 1$

Which is indeed true.

I'd like this to be checked. I haven't seen the official solution, so if it happens to match with that, do tell me.

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  How are you choosing the $x_i$?  I don't see how counting the number of possible differences tells you how to construct the $x_i$.

Comment: I'm not choosing $x_i$ yet. I'm assuming a set of 100 $x_i$ and then constructing them once I have the difference between all possible pairs

Comment: Ok.  How are you constructing them?  I don't see that anywhere.  Note:  it's not enough to just count the differences.  A set of $3$ numbers has $\binom 32=3$ differences, but that doesn't mean you can find $3$ numbers that match a specified list of $3$ differences.  You can't get the difference set $\{1,2,100\}$. say.

Comment: The crucial thing is, the difference-set belongs to the set $S$, hence the differences are always attainable. For example, I can get the two numbers 157 and 100 if I must use the difference 57. And so on for every difference(which doesn't belong to $A$)

Comment: My difference set, $\{1,2,101\}$ belongs to $S$ but you still can't construct it.  Look, maybe you have some idea of how to construct your set, but nothing you wrote even hints at it.

Comment: 1: 3 and 2. 2: 4 and 2. 101: 102 and 1. Similarly, every possible pair of the set of $x_i$ can be constructed, and hence, the set $x_i$ can be constructed

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  Give me three numbers $a<b<c$ such that $\{c-b,c-a,b-a\} =\{1,2,101\}$.

Comment: As another troubling sign, $\binom {101}2+\binom {100}2=10^5$ which is $\textit {a lot}$ less than $10^6-1$.  Do you believe the claim is still true if you replace $10^6$ with $10^5+3$, say?

Comment: @lulu I don't mean we create a one-one with the difference-set and the $x_i$ set. I mean we take the number of differences which are exactly equal to the number of $2-subsets$ of a $100-set$, then, for each difference we get a pair(which, of course can be done). Once we get all possible pairs, we get the set

Comment: As I say, I can't follow what you wrote.  If you had some argument for constructing the $x_i$ you should include it.  I don't see why, for example, you suggest that it's enough to show that every individual difference can be constructed.  Doing that will, inevitably, give you more differences (that's what goes wrong with $\{1,2,101\}$ for instance). But...do you believe the claim is true if we replace $10^6$ by $10^5+3$, or whatever?  That seems like a dramatic strengthening of the desired claim.

Comment: I see what you mean. Given the set of differences, we can only in general create a set much bigger than the desired set.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  But I think your idea of using inequalities is good. Try something like this:  Suppose we have a maximal set $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that the desired property holds and for which it is impossible to find a new $x_{n+1}$ to add to the list.  Now show that this means that $n>99$.   I think this works and I think it preserves the spirit of your argument.

Comment: (Agree with the error that lulu pointed out) You're actually reasonably close to an approach that works. You want to ensure that $x_m \neq x_k + a_i  - a_j $. How/when can we force that? (Relating $10^6 = (10^2)^3$ gives a hint that this is an appropriate equation to look at)